# How to use C# generics to simplify access to WinRT settings?

Tags: c#, generics

In WinRT, settings are stored as objects which means that you end up doing a lot of casting to get back to the type you want. Since that seems to map onto one of the reasons why generics were added to C#, I've been trying to simplify my code so that I can do something like:

```
    public string LastRunVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return GetLocalSettingsValue<String>("LastRunVersion", null);
        }

        set
        {
            SetLocalSettingsValue("LastRunVersion", value);
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is with the signature for SetLocalSettingsValue. I tried:

```
private T GetLocalSettingsValue<T>(string tag, T defaultValue) where T:Object
```

but Object isn't allowed because it isn't a valid constraint. I know that I only store booleans and strings, so I then tried:

```
private T GetLocalSettingsValue<T>(string tag, T defaultValue) where T:String, bool
```

but the compiler says that "A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter".

What do I need to do with the definition in order to allow me to use string and bool?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply create two methods one for bool and another for string. No reason for this method to be generic if you can use only two types as generic parameter.

Comment: In retrospect, that does indeed seem to be the simplest solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing two different methods, as Sriram suggests, does seem like the simplest solution for the immediate concern. That said, your generic approach is viable, has precedent, and will make it much easier to extend the code in the future.

In fact, what you tried was nearly correct. The main thing is that you don't actually need a constraint at all. The method declaration is fine without it, and though you don't show the method body, as long as all you need to do is cast some object reference to the type `T`, that will work:

```
private T GetLocalSettingsValue<T>(string tag, T defaultValue)
{
    object value;

    // initialize/retrieve the value somehow

    // Check for value present, return default if missing, cast otherwise
    return value != null ? (T)value : defaultValue;
}
```

In fact, since you are passing a default value, type inference will allow you to omit the type parameter in some cases. For example:

```
public string LastRunVersion
{
    get { return GetLocalSettingsValue("LastRunVersion", (string)null); }
}
```

If you had a non-null default value, the above would be more interesting. :) With the null value, you have to cast it to `string` just for the compiler to know what the correct type is, which is practically the same as just providing the type parameter. But if you were passing a `string` literal or the value of a `string` variable, the type would be clear and the name of the type would not need to be provided at all (not even as a cast).

More interesting is the `bool` scenario:

```
public string LastRunVersion
{
    get { return GetLocalSettingsValue("SomeBooleanSetting", false); }
}
```

Here, the literal has a clear type, and so you don't need to provide the type name in any form.

Finally, note that C# does have the idea of `default` values for types. If you want to support non-null, non-zero default values, then your current approach is good. However, if your defaults are always going to be things like `null`,  `false`, or `0` (e.g. for an `int`, should you ever need to store something like that), then you don't need the default parameter at all:

```
private T GetLocalSettingsValue<T>(string tag)
{
    object value;

    // initialize/retrieve the value somehow

    // Check for value present, return default if missing, cast otherwise
    return value != null ? (T)value : default(T);
}
```

Any reference type will use `null` as the default. For value types, you will get whatever the value would be if you created an instance using the parameterless constructor (all value types have a parameterless constructor). Numeric types all default to their version of 0, `bool` defaults to `false`, etc.

Naturally, in that case you will always have to provide the type parameter, since there aren't any arguments from which the type parameter could be inferred.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you *so* much. As you pointed out, I do need to support non-null, non-zero defaults but I appreciate your confirmation of default(T).